# Discrete Math - Proving one to one and onto for a function.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Determine whether the functions below is
onto, and/or one-to-one for $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

(a). $f(x) = (2x - 2)^2$.

**One to one proof:**

Direct method: Say $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $(2x_1 - 2)^2 = (2x_2 - 2)^2$, then $2x_1 - 2 = 2x_2 - 2$ and $2x_1 - 2 = 2 - 2x_2$.  Respectively, $x_1 = x_2$ and $x_1 = 4 - x_2$.  (Not sure what to say from here)

Using contraposition:  Say $x_1 \neq x_2$, for instance $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = 2$, Then $(2(0) - 2)^2 = 4$, and $(2(2) - 2)^2 = 4$, thus we have shown $f(0) = f(2)$, a contradiction to the defintion of one to one, therefore our function $f$ is not one to one. $\square$

My question is in regards to the direct method, I'm not sure logically what can be said to finalize the proof.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Look for a counterexample.

Comment: You should use the wolrd "or", either $x_2 = x_1$ or $x_1 = 4 - x_2$. From here, you already see it is not one to one due to multiple solutions. You give example to show it is not one to one to further the argument of f is not one to one is correct.

Comment: Thank you, do you know of any definitions that utilize the multiple solutions issue as a disproof?

Comment: Direct method (for showing $f$ is not onto): Every value of $f$ is nonnegative, QED. In what you have for "Direct method", the second possibility is $x_1 = 2- x_2$ not $4-x_2$. Using "and" reads funny: not "$2x_1−2=2x_2−2$ and $2x_1−2=2−2x_2$" but better "$2x_1−2=2x_2−2$ or $2x_1−2=2−2x_2$", or at least add "are possible solutions". So $x_1 = x_2$, or $x_1 = 2- x_2$. This shows you how to find counterexamples. For *any* $x_1$ let $x_2 = 2 - x_1$; then $x_1\ne x_2$, and $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

It does not follow from $(2x_1-2)^2=(2x_2-2)^2$ that $2x_1-2=2x_2-2$: all you can conclude is that

$$2x_1-2=\pm(2x_2-2)\;.$$

You can then go on and conclude that either $x_1=x_2$, or $2x_1-2=-(2x_2-2)$ and hence $x_1=2-x_2$. Since $2-x_2$ is not in general equal to $x_2$, this tells you that there must be a counterexample and even tells you how to find one: for instance, set $x_2=2$ and $x_1=0$.

Comment: Ah, very nice I see the error I made, I was trying to use my direct method to get insights into my indirect proof, but was off by 2, which explains my confusion.  Thank you!  Also, as you stated that immediately when I stated that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, I was already contradicting myself?

Comment: @javaderek: You’re welcome! No, when you try for a direct proof you should indeed start by assuming that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, so that was fine. The only problem was that you drew an incorrect conclusion which, if true, would have said that $f$ **was** one-to-one. The correct conclusion, on the other hand, points the way towards a counterexample.

Comment: I understand, thank you again!

Comment: @javaderek: My pleasure; glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_1 = -2$ and $x_2 = 4$

Then calculate $f(-2)$ and $f(4)$.  What does this mean?

Also, as you may have realized you've "proved" this both ways...your direct proof is incorrect.

Your mistake was writing (I paraphrase):

$x^2 = y^2 \to x=y$

Think +/-...

Answer (score 0):

$a^2 = b^2$ does not imply that $a = b$.

Instead, you can try to use

$$(2x_1 - 2)^2 = (2x_2 - 2)^2 \Leftrightarrow (x_1 - 1)^2 = (x_2 - 1)^2 $$

and then

$$(x_1 - 1)^2 - (x_2 - 1)^2 = (x_1 + x_2 - 2)(x_1 - x_2) = 0$$

Since $\mathbf{Z}$ is an integral domain (no zero divisors), this means that either $x_1 - x_2 = 0$ or $x_1 + x_2 - 2 = 0$. The latter equation has solutions in $\mathbf{Z}$ where $x_1 \ne x_2$ so this shows it is not injective.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 1-1: $f(0) = f(2)$ and there exists no integer $a$ such that $f(a) = -1$ so it is not surjective either.